# How to highlight table row based on condition in angularJs?

Tags: angularjs, angular

so I got the table where I display certain data which includes dates and other stuff. What I want is to highlight row where the displayed date is the same as the current day. Table is ordered by the dates. Any idea about this use-case?
This is my code:

```
 <table class="table table-striped" style="font-size:14px; margin-left: 5px;">
  <head>
   <tr>
     <th style="text-align: left;"><data-i18n i18n="_m_f_pen_feeding_start_date_">Feeding date</data-i18n></th>
     <th style="text-align: left;"><data-i18n i18n="_m_f_pen_frequency_of_feeding_">Frequency of feeding</data-i18n></th>
            <th></th>
   </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="freq in vm.details.pen_feeding_scheduler_list | orderBy:'-start_feeding_date'">
       <td style="min-width: 120px; text-align: left;">{{freq.start_feeding_date | date:'shortDate'}}</td>
       <td style="min-width: 120px; text-align: left;  display: inline-block;white-space: nowrap">{{freq.feeding_frequency || ('_label_empty_' | i18n)}}</td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
```

In my controller i set current date as :

```
 vm.current_date = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)
```

If you need more code, I can provide it. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can do it via `ng-class`. Write your logic in a function on controller and call it from html. `<td ng-class="getClass()">.....</td>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is fiddle link for a simple example. You can modify it as per your need.

```
<div ng-class="getClass()">text</div>
```

Controller:

```
var myModule = angular.module('app', []);
var current_date = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);

myModule.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {


  $scope.getClass = function(){
        if(current_date == '2020-07-23'){
      return 'blue';
      }else{
      return 'red';
      }
  }
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/5oc3fqzj/

Comment: current date should match date from ng-repeat, this doesn't help me

Comment: Dude I gave you the idea, write your own logic into that. Pass your date as an argument and verify it in the function, simple